# How render somewhat changeable select in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I can not understand how to make independent of each other selects, if I render all these selects through the map. How to implement correctly, given that in the future the data will be taken from redux store?

Detailed sample code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/v0z0o2qjo5)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select/Select";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel/InputLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl/FormControl";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem/MenuItem";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectValue: "",
    selectTitle: [
      {
        title: "Title1"
      },
      {
        title: "Title2"
      }
    ]
  };
  handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event.target);
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    const renderSelect = this.state.selectTitle.map((item, index) => 
      <FormControl key={index} style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "27px" }}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-auto-width">{item.title}</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={this.state.selectValue}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          inputProps={{
            name: "selectValue"
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    );
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {renderSelect}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** [Sample code with solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/jv3j8wx4k5)

Both selects have the same value because each `<Select>` element has a `value` prop pulling from the same `this.state.selectValue` in the state. You need to store each value separately in a way that corresponds to its title.

Something like:

```
state = {
  selectValue: {
    Title1: 10,
    Title2: 30
  },
  selectTitle: [
    {
      title: "Title1"
    },
    {
      title: "Title2"
    }
  ]
};
```

Then, make the changes in the component to correct read and write to the state.

Comment: I didn’t understand how it would help me?

Comment: Do not tell me the selected result in order to save, do I need to write it in redux?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I can load the data from the redux, and when choosing the select, record my choice also in the store? or will it be bad practice?